# Angular 2 Ionic 2 - How to set max or min date to today for date input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

```
 <input class="alert-input date-input" #dob="ngModel" name="dob" max="2018-03-07" [(ngModel)]="leadDetail.dob" type="date"></div>
```

How can I set the max date for today instead of 2018-03-07 dynamically?

I tried following methods-

```
 <input  max="today" type="date"></div>
 <input  max="{{today | date:'yyyy-mm-dd'}}" type="date"></div>
```

Class -

```
public today = new Date();
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input class="alert-input date-input" name="dob" [max]="today" type="date">


today = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
```

<kbd>[Working Example Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/HKeVKgH3Hi8MYbcdin80?p=preview)</kbd>

> Reason:

Because when you are using `new Date()` this will give you full date with time zone and time etc, you have to assign only Date so you have to split this with only Date.
For more clarification run this:

```
console.log(new Date(), '----', new Date().toJSON());
```

Comment: Awesome! :) Thanks.

Comment: really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

change mm to MM then the format but this will effect to the date you changed this wont help until unless its ngModel is bind to another variable

Answer (score 0):

**the submit button will be disabled if input date is greater than current date**

register.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitLoginForm(loginForm)" style="background-  color:beige;">
<input [(ngModel)]="vdate"  name="dob"  type="date">

<button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid || (today < vdate)" class="btn">Login</button>

</form>

</div>
```

register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-register',
templateUrl: './register.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
vdate: Date
today = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {

}
submitLoginForm() {
console.log("Welcome to Jollywood")
}
}
```