# ionic 2 datetime display current date to future date and focused on today's date

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-datetime

I'm currently developing an app using ionic 2.

My problem is about datetime: I have this code in my html

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="date" formControlName="date" displayFormat="MMMM DD, YYYY" min="2017" max="2100"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

The result is this => http://prntscr.com/fz5lx6

But I want to focus it to current date not to the maximum date.

How can I set that in ionic 2?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Ionic 2 - How to set max or min date to today for date input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366754/angular-2-ionic-2-how-to-set-max-or-min-date-to-today-for-date-input)

Comment: Its different, I want to focus to today's date and show future dates then disable past dates.

because I want that the users input that will not accept past date, only current date and future dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `[(ngModel)]="date"` is the right way to do it.
Now you can declare following variable in your Typescript file:

```
public date: string = new Date().toISOString();
```

This way, you creating a date, based on the actual time and formating it into a string that the `<ion-datetime>` component can work with.
A proper string could look like this:

```
2017-07-23T09:10:19.621Z
```

In this case you do not need the time behind the date, because you only use the date.

Comment: what to do when its inside `formGroup` as  a `formControlName` ?

Comment: @AnkurShah I think, this is not topic of this question. Maybe conside open a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

u can use this one too

```
currentDate: string = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

and it will look like this:

```
01/06/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same methodology as

```
myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
```

And in your ion-datetime do this instead:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" pickerFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following format:

```
captura : any = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: How is this any different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48985701/3784008) from a year ago?